# Title bar disappears when windows are maximized in KDE

Tags: kde, kwin

The box "No Border" in the windows operation menu is always checked on and I can't turn it off. Here are some images showing the problem[image]

On the other hand, when the windows are not maximized the title bar appears. 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I messed around with active window control and checked the hide title bar option then uninstalled it and the setting perdured. I reinstalled it and unchecked the option. Feels stupid.

Comment: Where can I see this option ?

Comment: In the settings of the active windows control widget.

Comment: Same here, not only you. I knew it was the problem but I didn't remeber at all the widget's name. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Latte:

You have to uncheck "Support borderless maximized windows in different layouts" under the latte settings -> Preferences -> Behavior
[image: screenshot]